# AngularJS: Keep track of user input in the URL so the user can take advantage of browser's back/forward

Tags: angularjs, pushstate, route-provider, location-provider

AngularJS's official tutorial is a great example of my problem. When you enter a query and choose the way it sorts results at http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-12/app/#/phones, the url stays the same and user output is not stored anywhere else either. Now if the user clicks a link, he can't go back to his filtered results. With more items and filters it becomes annoying.

What is the best approach to keeping user's filter selections and query in the URL? I tried using a combination of AngularJS's `$location` and `$routeParams` and browser's `history.pushState()`, however it became quite cumbersome and some things still don't work. Reading the 'Organizing Navigation' chapter of 'Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS' book didn't help either. There is no single piece of code I am concerned about, just the whole structure of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just answered a similar question for someone else. You can keep the state as a value around.

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MwJrk5?p=preview) as example.
Also see [this other question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22597545/248055).